# krukshal's algorithm or Prims Algorithm which one is better in finding minimum spanning tree?

Tags: algorithm, analysis, kruskals-algorithm, prims-algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kruskal vs Prim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195872/kruskal-vs-prim)

krukshal's algorithm or Prims Algorithm which one is better in finding minimum spanning tree?

Comment: @Adnan: how do you know this is homework?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195872/kruskal-vs-prim

Comment: Sounds very familiar to my algorithms analysis class question from a few years back

Comment: Simple answer: they're both still in wide/common use because either can be better depending on the nature of your graph, specifically number of nodes versus number of edges.

Comment: I took off the tag since it offended you so much and apparently it isn't homework. It wasn't meant to be offensive or accusatory, just trying to make this Q visible under homework tag.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add one point in favour of Prim's algorithm I haven't seen mentioned. If you are given N points and a distance function d(x,y) for the distance between x and y, it is easy to implement Prim's algorithm using space O(N) (but time N^2).

Start off with an arbitrary point A and create an array of size N-1 giving you the distances from A to all other points. Pick the point, B, associated with the shortest distance, link A and B in the spanning tree and then update the distances in the array to be the minimum of the distance already noted down to that other point and the distance from B ot that other point, noting down where the shortest link is from B and where from A. Carry on.

I don't know a similar way of handling Kruskal's algorithm for a dense graph specified by a distance function, and for large N you can run out of space O(N^2) before you run out of patience for time O(N^2).