Random sampling from ordered data
In a simulation, we need ordered data which is a random sample (with or without replacement) of size m from a full data set of size n. Unfortunately, ordering the sampled data turns out to be a performance bottleneck in our simulations. The problem is that the sampling is repeated R times, which results in a runtime complexity of O(R m log(m)). We are seeking to reduce the runtime complexity by calling sort() only once, before all sampling:
n <- 500; m <- 100; R <- 1000
all.data <- runif(n)
all.data <- sort(all.data)  # the full data set is already sorted
for (r in 1:R) {
  indices <- sample(1:n, m)
  sample.data <- sort(all.data[indices])  # this call to sort should be avoided
}

We therefore wonder whether it is possible to sort the full data set only once and then subsequently to directly obtain ordered samples by sampling from the ordered data (without ordering the indices returned by sample()).
Does anyone have a suggestion how to do this in R (we do not necessarily need R code, but the general approach would also be sufficient)?

If you could offer a reproducible example it would help enormously in identifying and correcting the bottleneck

If the full dataset is ordered and you sample using unordered indices, doesn't that make the sample unordered?  As @PGSA writes, a minimal reproducible example would help clarify the situation.

@PGSA I have added a code sample outlining our current approach and where the bottleneck is.

If you really can't afford to sort the indices, you could I guess precompute all possible unordered samples (i.e. n-choose-k) which would be very laborious for a large set, then randomly select one set each iteration...

Could you provide some more information at least - what size of m, n and R are we talking here?

n varies from 30 to 1000, different values for m are tried for each n, and R is 1000. Each combination is repeated N=10^6 times, because we are estimating a coverage probability.

precomputing the possible samples is not a good plan then - 1000 choose 10 (for example) offers 2.63E+23 possible sample sets.

@SamR I have edited the code to be runnable and also used realistic values for n, m, and R.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

For sampling without replacement, all.data[sample(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(m, n-m)))] may suffice.

For sampling with replacement (see below for references and a simulation check):
frexp <- function(m, R, x) {
  y <- rexp(R)
  for (r in 1:R) {
    cs <- cumsum(rexp(m))
    sample.data <- x[ceiling(cs*length(x)/(cs[m] + y[r]))]
  }
}

For sampling without replacement:
fbool2 <- function(m, R, x) {
  n <- length(x)
  b <- logical(n)
  for (r in 1:R) {
    b[i <- sample(n, m)] <- TRUE
    sample.data <- x[b]
    b[i] <- FALSE
  }
}

Other functions for benchmarking, including one that doesn't bother to sort:
fNoSort <- function(m, R, x) for (r in 1:R) sample.data <- sample(x, m)
fsort <- function(m, R, x) for (r in 1:R) sample.data <- sort(sample(x, m))
fbool1 <- function(m, R, x) { # from @lotus
  for (r in 1:R) sample.data <- x[sample(rep.int(!0:1, c(m, length(x) - m)))]
}

Benchmarking:
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  fNoSort = fNoSort(m, R, all.data),
  fsort = fsort(m, R, all.data),
  fbool1 = fbool1(m, R, all.data),
  fbool2 = fbool2(m, R, all.data),
  frexp = frexp(m, R, all.data)
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>     expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>  fNoSort  8.3386  8.52895  9.746159  8.80505  9.37925 19.4995   100
#>    fsort 35.6090 38.05500 40.689749 39.67485 41.73925 79.2346   100
#>   fbool1 29.2213 29.64240 31.838542 30.65475 32.70145 40.3151   100
#>   fbool2 10.2221 10.43100 11.616368 10.79390 12.22930 19.7826   100
#>    frexp  5.0672  5.16110  6.028450  5.30465  5.81935 16.2895   100

frexp is faster even than sample without the sort.
Quick simulation to check that the indices used in frexp constitute a (sorted) uniform random sample with replacement:
(seed <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1))
#> [1] 904968452
set.seed(seed)
n <- 20 # sample the numbers 1 through 20
N <- 1e6 # number of samples
tabulate(sample(n, N, 1), n)
#>  [1] 50176 50058 50270 50279 50208 49722 50005 49668 49856 50196 49890 49798
#> [13] 50163 49489 49918 49698 50052 50240 50333 49981
tabulate(ceiling((cs <- cumsum(rexp(N)))*n/(cs[N] + rexp(1))), n)
#>  [1] 49918 49883 49957 50063 49815 50226 49792 49970 49879 49788 50119 49965
#> [13] 50417 49832 50059 50281 49930 49904 50416 49786

References:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74218/relations-between-order-statistics-of-uniform-rvs-and-exponential-rvs
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63430876/9463489
https://djalil.chafai.net/blog/2014/06/03/back-to-basics-order-statistics-of-exponential-distribution/

The performance results are impressive. Can you please explain how frexp() works and why random numbers of the exponential distribution are generated?

I tweaked frexp for a little more speed and added a simulation check and some references at the bottom.

One possible method is to do systematic sampling on sorted sequences. For example, if 100 sorted indices are desired from 500, then partition the entire sample into 100 strata containing five indices and randomly sample 1 of these five. The resulting sample is automatically sorted.
pseudo.sort <- function() {
  size <- n/m
  indices <- sapply(1:m, function(i) sample(1:size + (size * (i-1)), 1))
  replicate(R, \() all.data[indices])
}

R <- 10000

pseudo.sort()
  [1]   4   8  13  17  21  29  35  38  44  46  55  56  61  69  72  77  82  89  93  98
 [21] 102 109 115 120 123 127 132 136 143 149 154 156 162 167 171 180 185 186 194 198
 [41] 202 208 214 216 221 226 233 240 243 246 255 257 264 266 271 276 284 290 294 300
 [61] 301 307 314 316 325 326 333 340 341 347 353 357 365 367 374 376 384 388 395 397
 [81] 404 406 414 418 422 428 432 440 445 447 454 456 464 468 471 477 485 489 492 496

Compare with an algorithm which sorts the sample indices:
sorted.sample <- \() {
  for (r in 1:R) {
    indices <- sort(sample(1:n, m)) # the sort has been shifted
    sample.data <- all.data[indices]  
  }
}

lotus.sort <- \() replicate(R, \() all.data[sample(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(m, n-m)))])

> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sorted.sample(), pseudo.sort(), lotus.sort())
Unit: microseconds
            expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
 sorted.sample() 44166.7 45439.5 50490.146 45936.05 47094.55 363412.8   100
   pseudo.sort()  1166.3  1201.5  1232.323  1225.90  1258.80   1400.6   100
    lotus.sort()   535.3   555.00   612.407   569.55   586.65  4126.2   100


This is very quick (and pre-sorted) but loses an element of 'true' random sampling.  It's an interesting approach.  Hopefully it strikes the balance that OP needs.

Random sampling can be simple or systematic. Both methods give a "true" random sample.

In that each member of the population has an equal chance of selection in a sample, yes, but doesn't this approach mean that some combinations are never selectable?  for example, no sample will have both 1 and 2 since they are both in the [1:5] stratum?  Have I misunderstood? This is new territory for me so I am keen to learn.

Yes - some combinations would be impossible. But each individual is equally likely to be sampled, which is the main point of random sampling. Systematic sampling is used to save on costs or for other logistic reasons. Here, it can be used instead of sorting.

The method by @lotus is exactly what I was looking for and solves the problem for sampling without replacement. Implementing an own sampling procedure, as you did, is somewhat risky due to many pitfalls in random number generation by means of modulo arithmetic. I would thus not trust the resulting coverage probabilities or confidence intervals obtained from "systematic" sampling: It is known, e.g., that jackknife sampling, a very systematic approach, does not produce a representative sampling distribution.

Thanks for the answers. As the most salient answer is buried in a comment by @lotus, let me summarize it as an answer.
For sampling without replacement, the indices can be sampled as a sequence of n boolean values (TRUE if the element is part of the sample) instead of a sequence of m numeric indices. This can be achieved in R with
selected <- sample(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), c(m, n-m)))
sample.data <- all.data[selected]

For sampling with replacement, a simple algorithm would be:

Initialize a count array c of size n with zeros
Select m times a number i from {1,2,...,n} and increase c[i] for each number
Eventually select each element as often as it is counted in c

A straightforward, albeit quite slow due to the for loop, implementation in R would be as follows:
c <- numeric(n)
is <- sample(1:n, m, replace=TRUE)
for (i in is) c[i] <- c[i] + 1
sample.data <- rep(all.data, c)

As suggested in a comment by @jblood94, the for loop can be circumvented with tabulate():
c <- tabulate(sample(n, m, replace=TRUE), n)
sample.data <- rep(all.data, c)

The same works with replace=FALSE, too.

Use tabulate to avoid the for loop: rep(x, tabulate(sample(n, m, 1), n)).

@jblood94 Yes that leads indeed to some speedup. Interestingly, it is faster than the sampling without replacement from a boolean vector.
